# ElasticSearch: aggregation on _score field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use the [stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) or [extended_stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html) aggregation on the `_score` field but can't find any examples of this being done (i.e., seems like you can only use aggregations with actual document fields).

**Is it possible to request aggregations on calculated "metadata" fields for each hit in an ElasticSearch query response (e.g., `_score`, `_type`, `_shard`, etc.)?**

I'm assuming the answer is 'no' since fields like `_score` aren't indexed...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note: The original answer is now outdated in terms of the latest version of Elasticsearch. The equivalent script using Groovy scripting would be:

```
{
    ...,
    "aggregations" : {
        "grades_stats" : { 
            "stats" : { 
                "script" : "_score" 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

In order to make this work, you will need to enable dynamic scripting or, even better, store a file-based script and execute it by name (for added security by not enabling dynamic scripting)!

---

You can use a script and refer to the score using doc.score. More details are available in ElasticSearch's scripting [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_score).

A sample stats aggregation could be:

```
{
    ...,
    "aggregations" : {
        "grades_stats" : { 
            "stats" : { 
                "script" : "doc.score" 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And the results would look like:

```
"aggregations": {
    "grades_stats": {
        "count": 165,
        "min": 0.46667441725730896,
        "max": 3.1525731086730957,
        "avg": 0.8296855776598959,
        "sum": 136.89812031388283
    }
}
```

A [histogram](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) may also be a useful aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
    "grades_histogram": {
        "histogram": {
            "script": "doc.score * 10",
            "interval": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Histogram results:

```
"aggregations": {
    "grades_histogram": {
        "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 3,
               "doc_count": 15
            },
            {
               "key": 6,
               "doc_count": 103
            },
            {
               "key": 9,
               "doc_count": 46
            },
            {
               "key": 30,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: As this answer predicts, I got an error about "scripts of type [inline], operation [aggs] and lang [groovy] are disabled". I seem to have sidestepped the restriction by using {"script": "_score", "lang": "expression"}, which works fine, even though I haven't enabled dynamic scripting.

Answer (score 10):

`doc.score` doesn't seem to work anymore. Using `_score` seems to work perfectly.

Example:

```
{
    ...,
    "aggregations" : {
        "grades_stats" : { 
            "stats" : { 
                "script" : "_score" 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```