# ElasticSearch: aggregation on _score field w/ Groovy disabled

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, scripting

Every example I've seen (e.g., [ElasticSearch: aggregation on _score field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557645/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-score-field)) for doing aggregations on or related to the _score field seems to require the usage of scripting. With ElasticSearch disabling dynamic scripting by default for security reasons, is there any way to accomplish this without resorting to loading a script file onto every ES node or re-enabling dynamic scripting?

My original aggregation looked like the following:

```
"aggs": {
    "terms_agg": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "field1",
            "order": {"max_score": "desc"}
        },
     "aggs": {
         "max_score": {
             "max": {"script": "_score"}
         },
         "top_terms": {
             "top_hits": {"size": 1}
         }
      }
}
```

Trying to specify expression as the lang doesn't seem to work as ES throws an error stating the score can only be accessed when being used to sort. I can't figure out any other method of ordering my buckets by the score field. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: To clarify, my restriction is not being able to modify the server-side. I.e., I cannot add or edit anything as part of the ES installation or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use the other scripting options available. `mvel` seems not to be possible to be used unless dynamic scripting is enabled. And, unless [a more fine-grained control of scripting enable/disable](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10116) reaches 1.6 version, I don't think is possible to enable dynamic scripting for `mvel` and not for `groovy`.

We are left with `native` and `mustache` (used for templates) that are enabled by default. I don't think custom scripting can be done with `mustache`, if it's possible I didn't find a way and we are left with `native` (Java) scripting.

Here's my take to this:

- create an implementation of `NativeScriptFactory`:

```
package com.foo.script;

import java.util.Map;

import org.elasticsearch.script.ExecutableScript;
import org.elasticsearch.script.NativeScriptFactory;

public class MyScriptNativeScriptFactory implements NativeScriptFactory {

    @Override
    public ExecutableScript newScript(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
        return new MyScript();
    }

}
```

- an implementation of `AbstractFloatSearchScript` for example:

```
package com.foo.script;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.elasticsearch.script.AbstractFloatSearchScript;

public class MyScript extends AbstractFloatSearchScript {

    @Override
    public float runAsFloat() {
        try {
            return score();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

- alternatively, build a simple Maven project to tie all together. pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <elasticsearch.version>1.5.2</elasticsearch.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

- build it and get the resulting jar file.
- place the jar inside [ES_folder]/lib
- edit `elasticsearch.yml` and add

  `script.native.my_script.type: com.foo.script.MyScriptNativeScriptFactory`
- restart ES nodes.
- use it in aggregations:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "max_score": {
      "max": {
        "script": "my_script",
        "lang": "native"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My sample above just returns the `_score` as a script but, of course, it can be used in more advanced scenarios.

EDIT: if you are not allowed to touch the instances, then I don't think you have any options.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an ideal solution. Further, it'd be considerably easier to just write a groovy script and place it in <config_path>/scripts/. For example, in my case I could write `_score` in a file called _score.groovy and place it in scripts/ and it would be automatically picked up by ES. From my testing, I wouldn't even have to change the `{"script": "_score"}` code to use "script_file", it would just work. The problem is, this solution requires direct access to modify the nodes, which I can't guarantee.

Comment: I gave you an alternative, the only one possible in my opinion given your restrictions. You said you don't want to use Groovy (because of the dynamic scripting thing) and don't want to "load a script file onto every ES node or re-enabling dynamic scripting". If you, instead, want to use script files, then yes - easier, but you said you don't want to do that. If you keep your initial restrictions, I don't think there is any other way than a `native` script. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, then I guess my restrictions weren't clear enough, as your alternative falls into that bucket (no pun intended). My restriction is an ES cluster that I have no control over and cannot modify the configuration of. I'll edit the post to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch at least of version 1.7.1 and possibly earlier also offers the use of Lucene's Expression scripting language – and as Expression is sandboxed by default it can be used for dynamic inline scripts in much the same way that Groovy was. In our case, where our production ES cluster has just been upgraded from 1.4.1 to 1.7.1, we decided not to use Groovy anymore because of it's non-sandboxed nature, although we really still want to make use of dynamic scripts because of the ease of deployment and the flexibility they offer as we continue to fine-tune our application and its search layer.

While writing a native Java script as a replacement for our dynamic Groovy function scores may have also have been a possibility in our case, we wanted to look at the feasibility of using Expression for our dynamic inline scripting language instead. After reading through the documentation, I found that we were simply able to change the "lang" attribute from `"groovy"` to `"expression"` in our inline `function_score` scripts and with the `script.inline: sandbox` property set in the `.../config/elasticsearch.yml` file – the function score script worked without any other modification. As such, we can now continue to use dynamic inline scripting within ElasticSearch, and do so with sandboxing enabled (as Expression is sandboxed by default). Obviously other security measures such as running your ES cluster behind an application proxy and firewall should also be implemented to ensure that outside users have no direct access to your ES nodes or the ES API. However, this was a very simple change, that for now has solved a problem with Groovy's lack of sandboxing and the concerns over enabling it to run without sandboxing.

While switching your dynamic scripts to Expression may only work or be applicable in some cases (depending on the complexity of your inline dynamic scripts), it seemed it was worth sharing this information in the hopes it could help other developers.

As a note, one of the other supported ES scripting languages, Mustache only appears to be usable for creating templates within your search queries. It does not appear to be usable for any of the more complexing scripting needs such as `function_score`, etc., although I am not sure this was entirely apparent during the first read through of the updated ES documentation.

Lastly, one further issue to be mindful of is that the use of Lucene Expression scripts are marked as an *experimental feature* in the latest ES release and the documentation notes that as this scripting extension is undergoing significant development work at this time, its usage or functionality may change in later versions of ES. Thus if you do switch over to using Expression for any of your scripts (dynamic or otherwise), it should be noted in your documentation/developer notes to revisit these changes before upgrading your ES installation next time to ensure your scripts remain compatible and work as expected.

For our situation at least, unless we were willing to allow non-sandboxed dynamic scripting to be enabled again in the latest version of ES (via the `script.inline: on` option) so that inline Groovy scripts could continue to run, switching over to Lucene Expression scripting seemed like the best option for now.

It will be interesting to see what changes occur to the scripting choices for ES in future releases, especially given that the (apparently ineffective) sandboxing option for Groovy will be completely removed by version 2.0. Hopefully other protections can be put in place to enable dynamic Groovy usage, or perhaps Lucene Expression scripting will take Groovy's place and will enable all the types of dynamic scripting that developers are already making use of.

For more notes on Lucene Expression see the ES documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts – this page is also the source of the note regarding the planned removal of Groovy's sandboxing option from ES v2.0+. Further Lucene Expression documentation can be found here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/expressions/index.html?org/apache/lucene/expressions/js/package-summary.html