# Query without using dynamic scripting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have the following query which currently uses dynamic scripting. I have since found that my host doesn't support this, as it has wider reaching security implications. How would I rewrite this script so that it doesn't use dynamic script?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_cells": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "loc": {
            "top_left": "58.645976, -13.515625",
            "bottom_right": "50.524473, 2.436523"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cells": {
          "geohash_grid": {
            "field": "loc",
            "precision": 2
          },
          "aggs": {
            "center_lat": {
              "avg": {
                "script": "doc['loc'].lat"
              }
            },
            "center_lon": {
              "avg": {
                "script": "doc['loc'].lon"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you [move the script to file](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting)? Or, better said, does your host allow you to place .groovy files inside the ES installation directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [store your scripts on the file system](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) and reference them from within your query/aggregations.

Create a file named `config/scripts/lat.groovy` with the following content

```
 doc['loc'].lat
```

Create another file named `config/scripts/lon.groovy` with the following content

```
 doc['loc'].lon
```

Then change your query to this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_cells": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "loc": {
            "top_left": "58.645976, -13.515625",
            "bottom_right": "50.524473, 2.436523"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cells": {
          "geohash_grid": {
            "field": "loc",
            "precision": 2
          },
          "aggs": {
            "center_lat": {
              "avg": {
                "script_file": "lat"
              }
            },
            "center_lon": {
              "avg": {
                "script_file": "lon"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: "Indexing your scripts" will not work if dynamic scripting is disabled ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from placing the actual script on a `.groovy` file, like I mentioned (more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting)), you could define a `native` script. More involved than the groovy-on-file approach but is much more flexible. In your case, the script is really simple :-) and you don't need the flexibility though, but the option exists (implementation sample from yours truly): [ElasticSearch: aggregation on _score field w/ Groovy disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086403/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-score-field-w-groovy-disabled/30094353#30094353)