# ElasticSearch: is-it possible to break query results after score changes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know if there is a way to stop the result list after the score has changed.

For example, with my query, I will get:

- 10 results with same score of 7.08979
  ... break the results, I don't need the other ones
- 3 results with same score 6.7865
- 8 results with same score 3.13467

Is there a feature for that ?

Else, I will need to run 2 queries: 1 to get first result with the score wanted, then another using the score found.

Comment: How about [aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557645/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-score-field) on `_score` and get the bucket of the score you want?

Comment: I will have a look at this. Thanks.