# ElasticSearch 5.0: aggregation on _score field?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm migrating my Elasticsearch queries from the 1.7 version to 5.0 (the latest at this moment) and I'm having some trouble with aggregations.

I want to do aggregation on a given field and show the top 5 documents ordered by score. From what I've read this used to be done like this:

```
"aggs" : {
    "max_price" : { "max" : { "script" : "_score" } }
}
```

Using Sense, the answer I get is "Unexpected token VALUE_STRING [script] in [top_score]."

Anyone went through this?

Note: For an older version an answer was posted here: [ElasticSearch: aggregation on _score field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557645/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-score-field)

Answer (score 0):

The default scripting language for Elasticsearch is now Painless instead of groovy.  According to [How to use scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html), you could try:

```
"aggs" : {
    "max_price": {
        "max": {
            "script": {
                "lang": "groovy", 
                "inline": "_score"
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Updated in Elasticsearch 5.x, there will be deprecated logs like:

> [WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead

The more correct way is:

```
"aggs" : {
    "max_price": {
        "max": {
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless", 
                "inline": "_score"
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the top 5 documents by score, overall, for your search terms, you can just set the size of your query to 5 and that should do the trick (eg below)

`{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "my_field": "whatever"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "my_other_field": "whatever else"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": [],
      "filter": []
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "something": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my_term"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "field_stats": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

On the other hand, if you want the top 5 scoring documents for each bucket, have you considered using a top hits aggregation? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html