# How to get sum of score column from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, odbc, nest, cdata, cdata-drivers

I am new to Elasticsearch. I tried to get result from ES using CData Elasticsearch ODBC driver. Is it possible to get sum of score field?

My code:

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={CData ODBC Driver for Elasticsearch};server=localhost");
        connection.Open();
        string query = "select sum(_score) from ordersdetails";
        OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(query, connection);
        OdbcDataReader dataReader = odbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(dataReader);
        connection.Close();
```

I have faced the below exception

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [HY000] The '_score' column is not applicable to the sum function.'

But the below query returns result:

"select _id, sum(_score) from ordersdetails group by _id"

Anybody know, Why I got exception when tried to get a result for a single column?

If you know the solution, please share with me.

Comment: Please tell me does sum query work for other numeric fields? Do you realize that `_score` is a ["virtual" field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) that is computed per each pair of (query, result)?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev : Yes. sum query works for other numeric fields.  Actually my use case is to getting ElasticSearch data through ODBC driver in application like Tableau, Power BI. I have not much knowledge about Elasticsearch. So I inserted data into elasticsearch using C# code. Please let us know, there is any possibility to get sum of score value using sql query?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev: Could you please provide me a example for usage of _score field?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `_score` field is the score of the document's relevance to the query fired. For instance, if you do a full text search on a set of tweets with query like `tweetText=google` ElasticSearch will return results in order of relevance and `_score` will contain the actual value that it used for sorting the results. That's why for me the use case from the question does not make sense - there is no query, and such `sum` does not give much information. May you provide your use case for summing the `_score`?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a couple of experiments with [`pyodbc`](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/EEC/odbc/pg_usageinpython.htm) and ElasticSearch I come to these conclusions:

1. CData ODBC driver knows that it is not possible to do aggregation on `_score` and does not let the user to do so
2. Behavior where it actually computes aggregation by `_score` is most likely a bug and is performed not by ElasticSearch but by the driver.

In short, don't use `_score` for any `GROUP BY`, it's a special feature of ElasticSearch dedicated to relevance sorting.

### A bit of introduction

As I already mentioned in the comments to the question, `_score` in ElasticSearch is a measure of how document is relevant to a given query (see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html)):

> The relevance score of each document is represented by a positive
>   floating-point number called the _score. The higher the _score, the
>   more relevant the document.

This field is not a part of the document and is computed for every query and every document. In ElasticSearch `_score` is used for [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_order). However, `_score` [is not always computed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html#_sorting_by_field_values), for instance when sorting on an existing field is required:

> The _score is not calculated, because it is not being used for sorting.

Since this field is computed on-the-fly, it is not possible to create efficient aggregation, hence ElasticSearch does not allow this directly. However, this still can be achieved by [using scripts in the aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557645/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-score-field).

### CData ODBC Driver is aware of _score field

CData ODBC Driver [is aware of `_score` field](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/EEC/odbc/pg_QueryMapping.htm):

> When the _score column is selected, scoring will be requested by
>   issuing a query context request, which scores the quality of the
>   search results. By default, results are returned in descending order
>   based on the calculated _score. An ORDER BY clause can be specified to
>   change the order of the returned results.
>
> When the _score column is not selected, a filter context will be sent,
>   in which case Elasticsearch will not compute scores. The results for
>   these queries will be returned in arbitrary order unless an ORDER BY
>   clause is explicitly specified.

Basically, this means that by explicitly mentioning `_score` in your query will make ODBC return such field (which might to be there by default).

### The experiments

I installed pyodbc and set up ElasticSearch 5.4 at my localhost. I tuned ES to log all the queries it receives.

#### 1.

At first I reproduced the first case:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sum(_score) FROM my_index.my_type")
```

And received this exception:

```
[HY000] The '_score' column is not applicable to the sum function.
```

In the log of ES I catched this query:

```
{"from":0,"size":100}
```

#### 2.

Next I took the second query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT _id, sum(_score) FROM my_index.my_type GROUP BY _id")
```

Which executed without exceptions, but resulted in this ES query:

```
{"from":0,"size":10000,"_source":{"includes":["_id","_score"],"excludes":[]}}
```

#### 3.

Then I tried to mock the library with non existing fields:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sum(score42) FROM simple_index.simple_type")
```

In this case exception was different:

```
[HY000] 'score42' is not a valid column.
```

Although the query sent to ES was the same as in the first case.

#### 4.

Then I tried to find out how does the library send aggregate requests:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sum(likes) FROM simple_index.simple_type GROUP BY likes")
```

In fact, it did use ES aggregations:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "likes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "likes",
        "size": 2147483647,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "sum_likes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "likes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Conclusions

The fact that the library is able to recognize `_score` as a special keyword, and also because it did not attempt to generate ES aggregations when asked for `sum(_score)`, I assume that it does not allow in general to do aggregations on `_score` and the "working" case here is likely a bug.